# Prove that $\tan(x)\tan(x+r) = \frac{\tan(x+r) - \tan(x)}{\tan r} -1$

Tags: algebra-precalculus, trigonometry

$\tan(x)\cdot \tan(x+r) = \dfrac{\tan(x+r) - \tan(x)}{\tan r} -1$

I tried L.H.S = $\dfrac{\sin(x)\cdot \sin(x+r)}{\cos(x)\cdot \cos(x+r)}$
= $\dfrac{\sin(x+r- x)}{\sin(r)}\dfrac{\sin(x)\cdot\sin(x+r)}{\cos(x)\cdot \cos(x+r)}$

= $\dfrac{\sin(x+r- x)}{\sin(r)}\dfrac{\sin(x)\cdot\sin(x+r)}{\cos(x)\cdot\cos(x+r)}$

= $\dfrac{\sin(x)\cdot\sin(x+r)}{\sin(r)}\dfrac{\sin(x+r)\cos(x) - \cos(x+r)\cos(x)}{\cos(x)\cdot \cos(x+r)}$

= $\dfrac{\sin(x)\cdot\sin(x+r)}{\sin(r)}\left(\tan(x+r) -\tan(x)\right)$

I get stuck here; what else is there to do?

Edit: using [Tavish's hint](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/4070822/892742), we can get it directly.

$$\tan(x+r -x) = \dfrac{\tan(x+r) - \tan(x)}{1 + \tan(x+r)\tan(x)}$$
$$1 + \tan(x+r)\tan(x)= \dfrac{\tan(x+r) - \tan(x)}{\tan(r)}$$
$$\tan(x+r)\tan(x) = \dfrac{\tan(x+r) - \tan(x)}{\tan(r)} -1$$

Comment: Please write (trigonometric) functions with  \. So that with \tan(x) you get $\tan(x)$ and not $tan(x)$. (Way easier to read)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Hint:

Use $$\tan(a-b)=\frac{\tan a -\tan b}{1+\tan a \tan b} $$ with $a=x+r, b=x$.

Comment: Thanks! I solved it now, should I edit my question or just accept this?

Comment: @Ceres No problem. You’re supposed to accept this answer.